# Segment FFmpeg output at its keyframe

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to segment a video file at its keyframes:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 30 -i :0.0 \
       -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=1:min-keyint=2:no-scenecut \
       -force_key_frames "expr:gte(1,0)" -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
       -f ssegment -segment_format mp4 \
       -segment_format_options movflags=+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof \
  out%03d.mp4
```

Every frame is a keyframe, so segment should split at every frame, but it doesn't. The splitted files contains multiple keyframes, and can't play properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segment muxer cuts only at keyframes (normally) but not automatically at each keyframe. You haven't set, or more precisely, overridden the segment duration option.

So,

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 30 -i :0.0 \
       -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=1 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
       -f ssegment -segment_time 0.001 -segment_format mp4 \
       -segment_format_options movflags=+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof \
  out%03d.mp4
```

With keyint=1 (which is equivalent to max KF interval), you don't need min-keyint or scenecut or force_key_frames.